# Maven Module issue

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies

I have an issue with maven . I Dont know if it's a setting issue eclipse side, maven side.
After creating the maven project, i create the module. But the issue is, after clicking finish, i have this failure message saying : 
"An internal error occurred during: "Creating project "".
   Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;

What does it mean? Is that a problem for after?

i searched for it everywhere but i found nothing.
Any help would be really appreciated

thanks

Comment: try to reload all dependencys. but it's just a wild guess

Comment: Can you paste the full error?

Comment: Do maven Stuff from the command line.  M2e respects eclipse settings which may conflict.

Comment: Hi this what i get as soon as the module is loading right after i created it : "An internal error occurred during:"Creating project blabla"". "    and the details of the error says : "An internal error occurred during: "Creating project "hello"".
Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;"     i have no ideas on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi again i have found the origin of the issue : eclipse knew issues to download the libraries because it was corrupted by the repository in .m2 file. i created a project and module via the command line , did mvn clean install, then checked the link informed  so after i erased the file and via the command line i did : mvn clean install again and forced the downloading of the repository files.....and it works !! build success and ok in eclipse :)